# Probability - throwing a dice ten times

Tags: probability, dice

> A fair dice was thrown 10 times. What is the probability that at least one of the numbers 1-6 appeared exactly 5 times?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean "exactly $5$ times "  or "at least $5$ times" ?

Comment: Good question. I mean "exactly 5 times".

Comment: Either way, Hint:  The events "$A$ is thrown five times" and "$B$ is thrown five times" are nearly mutually exclusive (if $A\neq B$).  Therefor the answer is nearly $6\times P(1)$  (where $P(1)$ is the probability that $1$ is thrown five times).  You just have to subtract off the cases where two numbers are thrown five times.

Comment: @lulu: Inclusion-Exclusion really needs to be invoked. This is because $1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2$ is valid, but counted twice.

Comment: @robjohn  I specifically said you had to subtract the cases where two numbers are thrown five times.

Comment: "subtract off the cases where two numbers are thrown five times" was unclear whether you were subtracting all the cases where two numbers were thrown five times or just the number to account for any double counting. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that a given number is thrown exactly $5$ times is
$$
\overbrace{\ \ \binom{10}{5}\ \ }^{\substack{\text{the number}\\\text{of ways to}\\\text{arrange the}\\\text{two groups}}}\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac16\right)^5\ }^{\substack{\text{probability}\\\text{of choosing}\\\text{five of the}\\\text{given number}}}\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac56\right)^5\ }^{\substack{\text{probability}\\\text{of choosing}\\\text{five of the}\\\text{other numbers}}}
$$
There are $\binom{6}{1}$ possibilities for the given number.

The probability that two given numbers are thrown exactly $5$ times is
$$
\overbrace{\ \ \binom{10}{5}\ \ }^{\substack{\text{the number}\\\text{of ways to}\\\text{arrange the}\\\text{two groups}}}\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac16\right)^5\ }^{\substack{\text{probability}\\\text{of choosing}\\\text{five of the}\\\text{first number}}}\overbrace{\ \ \left(\frac16\right)^5\ }^{\substack{\text{probability}\\\text{of choosing}\\\text{five of the}\\\text{other number}}}
$$
There are $\binom{6}{2}$ possibilities for the given numbers.

[Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) says that the probability that at least one number is thrown $5$ times is
$$
\binom{6}{1}\binom{10}{5}\left(\frac16\right)^5\left(\frac56\right)^5-\binom{6}{2}\binom{10}{5}\left(\frac16\right)^{10}=\frac{43715}{559872}
$$